# How to Install C++ Templates VS2012 Express Desktop

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I currently use [VS2012 Express for Windows Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34673) for Python/web development ([PTVS](http://pytools.codeplex.com/)). I need to work on some c++ projects, but the c++ templates are missing when I attempt to create a [new c++ project](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devschool/archive/2013/01/08/writing-your-first-c-program-using-visual-studio-2012.aspx). For example a Win32 Console Application.

Typical c++ templates (picture from online tutorial):

[image: Typical Templates]

Here are the options I am presented with on my machine:

[image: Missing Templates]

So far I've tried 1) repair from the install media, 2) `devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates` (later finding [a note](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms241279%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that this will not work on express editions. Can anyone tell me how to install the templates for c++ development? Setting up PTVS isn't very straightforward so I'd prefer not to uninstall/reinstall VS. My other option is to download and install VS2013. I'm just confused as to why the c++ templates aren't there when the download page clearly states this version supports c++ development.

Comment: Where did you download your copy of visual studio from?

Comment: Microsoft. The very first hyperlink that I provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem.

In order to use Python Tools for Visual Studio ([PTVS](https://pytools.codeplex.com/)), one must install the [VS isolated shell](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40764) and the [VS integrated shell](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40777). These two shells start up a separate development environment `devenv.exe` which looks like it reads `devenv.exe.config` or `devenv.pkgdef` for shell configuration items. The "normal" VS 2013 Shell is still there but must be launched from `WDExpress.exe`. The "normal" shell still contains the templates while the "integrated" shell only has project templates for tools you install/configure, such as PTVS.

Answer (score -1):

Try compiling this piece of code and show us any error.

```
#include <map>

std::map < int, int > x;
```

I think you are confusing project templates with c++ templates.

Comment: He is asking about options to create a C++ project in visual studio. Nothing to do with that sort of template.